# Is it possible to run npm install on a 512mo raspberry pi?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

When I run `npm i` on a 512 mo raspberry pi I get this Out of Memory error.

[image]

The app is a classic angular app with a lot of dependencies but not anything crazy at all.

Do you think it's even possible with 512 mo?
How could I make it work?

Comment: sure, if you can create some swap space, will be slow

Comment: I've set a swap but docker doesn't seems to use it. See the screenshot here :https://iili.io/HcMYOCb.jpg. I think docker should be smart enough to go for the memory if needed but it doesn't seem to be the case. I don't really have any ideas.

Comment: Are you running a full X11 desktop? Maybe you can go headless and save a load of RAM.

Comment: Indeed I chose the recommended default image with the official raspberry imager tool. This image contains a desktop. I will change to the OS lite without desktop. That's a good point, thanks.

Comment: Cool - let us know how you get on, please.

Comment: I ended building the angular app on my local computer and send it via scp to run it on the pi. I know I could do this with docker but I don't know how to build and upload the image somewhere. 512mo isn't simply enough to build an angular app.